# How does equalizer (category theory) characterize set theory equalizer?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions, category-theory

In the category Set, the equalizer of $f: A \to B$ is the (largest) set of elements $x \in A$ such that $f(x) = g(x)$.

But in category theory, this is generalized to a map $E \xrightarrow{e} A$ such that $f\circ e = g\circ e$ and such that the UMP holds.

But looking back at the set example, can't you take a smaller subset than the largest and surely that would (the inclusion) be a map $e$.  In other words, how does being an equalizer ensure that $E$ is indeed the "largest" object?

Comment: The universal property says that if there's any other map $h\colon X \to A$ such that $f \circ h = g \circ h$, then there's a unique map $\bar h \colon X \to E$ that factorises $h$ as $h = e \circ \bar h$. Now if $E$ (with $e$) is not the equaliser in the usual set-theory sense, let take $X$ with $h$ to be the actual equaliser. Can $\bar h \circ e$ be equal to $h$ (if, as you said, $E$ is "smaller")?

Comment: Intuitively, you may want to look at it like this: The map coming into $E$ from all other objects satisfying the condition is what makes it the "largest" possible object satisfying the condition — you can see this in other examples of universal objects also. Similarly, if the universal property forces a map going _out of_ the object into all possible objects, it will be the _smallest_ object satisfying the condition.

Comment: @M.Vinay thanks I like that explanation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $e:E\to A$ be a categorical equalizer of $f,g:A\to B$, and let $D$ be the set-theoretical equalizer. What we want to show is that the image of $e$ is $D$.

To see this, let $d:D\hookrightarrow A$ be the obvious inclusion. Since $f\circ d=g\circ d$, by the universal property of $e$, $d$ must factor through it - there is some $c:D\to E$ such that $d=e\circ c$. Since $d$ is onto $D$, so must be $e$.